# How can I auto refresh my web browser in android? (Any web browser)

Tags: browser

I want to refresh (reload) a webpage every x minutes. How can i do this? Firefox addon's don't work, dolphin addon's don't work either...

Comment: Why don't the work? I've tried [dolphin add on](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.tabreload&hl=en) here on an S4, a nexus 4, 5 and 7 (2013 edition), a Galaxy Tab, a HTC One M7 and M8.... Can you give more detail?

Comment: it seems that the addon only works if the browser is open, when you open another app or wait 30 min without opening the browser again it stops realoading the webpage.

Comment: Android *might* be killing the browser after a long time of inactivity... I don't know how to work around that to refresh a website with any of those tools.

Answer (score 0):

Install Tasker *https://play.google.com/store/search?c=apps&q=tasker+apk*

Read about Tasker and how to use *http://tasker.dinglisch.net/*

> Tasker is an application for Android which performs tasks (sets of actions) based on contexts (application, time, date, location, event, gesture) in user-defined profiles or in clickable or timer home screen widgets.

Download a script or write one to start and continue refreshing the browser at needed intervals.

> https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/tasker

*Always do a backup!!!!*